# Is it possible to use Entity method inside Sonata Admin class?

Tags: sonata-admin

Is it possible to use inside Sonata Admin class an Entity method that is not getter of property?

I would like add to `$listMapper->add('sum')` ...

```
class OrderAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->add('sum') //Order::getSum()
            ...
```

... result of `getSum()`

```
class /Entity/Order{
    ...
    public function getSum()
    {
        foreach ( ... ) {
           $sum += ...
        }
        return $sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use name of that method:

```
$listMapper
    ->add('getSum',null, ['label'=>'Sum'])
```